# Subset List of parent List not binding to Listbox in Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2013, data-binding, listbox

I am trying to bind a List of a custom class to a Listbox and cannot get anything to display. The List is a subset of another List. I can bind the parent List and see the items, but not the child List. How can I get the subset List to bind to the Listbox? I have tried changing the order of the ListBox's DisplayMember, ValueMember, and DataSource properties. In debugging I can see that the DataSource has the correct values, but I can't get them to display. Relevant code below:

```
public class DimZone
{
    public int Zone_Key { get; set; }
    public int Zone_ID { get; set; }
    public int Facility_Key { get; set; }
    public string Zone_Name { get; set; }
    public string Zone_Type { get; set; }
}
```

GlobalVariables Class containing global List collection:

```
public static List<DimZone>[] zoneCollection = new List<DimZone>[maxServerCount];
```

Form using global List collection and subset List:

```
List<DimZone> zoneCollectionAppended = new List<DimZone>();

private void StaffStatusReportForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        facilityComboBox.DataSource = GlobalVariables.facilityCollection;
        GetFacilityIndex();
        CreateZoneAppendedList();
        PopulateUI();
    }

private void CreateZoneAppendedList()
    {
        foreach (var zone in GlobalVariables.zoneCollection[currentFacilityIndex])
        {
            if (zone.Zone_Name != "All")
            {
                zoneCollectionAppended.Add(zone);
            }
        }
    }

private void PopulateUI()
    {
        if (zoneCollectionAppended != null)
        {
            zoneListBox.DisplayMember = "Zone_Name";
            zoneListBox.ValueMember = "Zone_ID";
            zoneListBox.DataSource = zoneCollectionAppended;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was I was changing `zoneListBox.DataSource` from one source to another on load, which caused the error. In order for the DataSource to update properly, I had to set `zoneListBox.DataSource = null` before updating to a new DataSource. I don't know why I have to set it to null first, but it solved my problem. So my updated code is as follows:

```
private void PopulateUI()
{
    if (zoneCollectionAppended != null)
    {
        zoneListBox.DisplayMember = "Zone_Name";
        zoneListBox.ValueMember = "Zone_ID";

        //DataSource had to be reset to null before updating to new DataSource
        zoneListBox.DataSource = null;

        zoneListBox.DataSource = zoneCollectionAppended;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code contains various unclear parts. In any case, the best proceeding in these situations is setting up a properly-working simpler code and modifying it until reaching the stage you want. I can provide this properly-working first step. Sample code:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<DimZone> source = new List<DimZone>();
    DimZone curZone = new DimZone() { Zone_Key = 1, Zone_ID = 11, Facility_Key = 111, Zone_Name = "1111", Zone_Type = "11111" };
    source.Add(curZone);
    curZone = new DimZone() { Zone_Key = 2, Zone_ID = 22, Facility_Key = 222, Zone_Name = "2222", Zone_Type = "22222" };
    source.Add(curZone);

    zoneListBox.DisplayMember = "Facility_Key";
    zoneListBox.DataSource = source;
}

public class DimZone
{
    public int Zone_Key { get; set; }
    public int Zone_ID { get; set; }
    public int Facility_Key { get; set; }
    public string Zone_Name { get; set; }
    public string Zone_Type { get; set; }
}
```

Try this code and confirm that the changes in `zoneListBox.DisplayMember` (e.g., `"Zone_Key"`, `"Zone_ID"`, etc.) are immediately reflected in the values being displayed by `zoneListBox`.

Comment: Sorry, I'm trying to be clear but it can be hard when I've been used to working with this code base. I can get basic binding with any properties to work with the List GlobalVarables.zoneCollection[currentFacilityIndex]. As soon as I switch to the zoneCollectionAppended List it does not function properly. Something is wrong with binding to the list and I don't understand why. The only difference between the two lists is that one list doesn't contain an "All" member. I need to alter the UI so that "All" does not display in the Listbox without changing the GlobalVariables.zoneCollection[].

Comment: @mlabus93 The only difference between `zoneCollectionAppended` and the code in my answer is that it is a global variable (what does not matter at all; on the other hand, it does not seem required in your situation). If you are not affecting the `zoneListBox` in any other way, your code should work fine. The most likely reason to have an unexpected behaviour is that the `DataSource` does not contain what you think (cannot tell from you code). Have you debugged the code? Are you sure that `zoneCollectionAppended` contains all the values you think it contains?

Comment: @mlabus93 As said, keep it simple. Open a new solution, write my code (including the hardcoded inputs) and keep evolving it until finding the problem. Although as said, this situation seems quite clear and doing a step-by-step debugging should help you understand what is wrong with the `DataSource` (because something has to be wrong with it).

Comment: Alright, I will try using your code and building it up. I set my DataSource to zoneCollectionAppended and debugged it with a breakpoint at the binding code line. I could clearly see my data showing up in zoneCollectionAppended with the proper values. When i step to the next line I can see the zoneListBox.DataSource also has the correct values so it is perplexing. Thanks for the help, though.

Comment: @mlabus93 I insist: what you are reporting doesn't make any sense. There are two likely reasons to explain why something not making any sense can happen: a .NET bug (very unlikely here); or that some other part of your code is not behaving as you expect (= something you did somewhere else in your code is affecting this part). Thus, the best approach is re-doing everything from a properly-working code (as the one I am providing). There is nothing else I (or any other person) can do to help you under these conditions.